# Using .hide() completely crashes IE 8

Tags: jquery, html-table

I wrote some simple jQuery code to try and hide rows of an html table based on the data inside one of the rows columns. The code I wrote works fine in all browsers except IE8, where it completely crashes (IE stops responding, tries to reload the tab and than reports that the page could not load).

If I include

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

the page no longer crashes, but it would be preferable to actually solve this issue rather than applying workarounds.

Here is a sample of the HTML table, and the jQuery code I am using to hide/show rows.

```
<table>
<thead> ... headers, table has 8 columns </thead>
<tbody>
<!--- The fifth column has a date I need to use to hide/show the rows -->
<tr> ... <td>9/27/2011</td> ... </tr>
...
</tbody>
</table>


function filterData() {
            $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").attr("checked", false);

            //This gets me the date to filter on
            var filterDate = new Date($("#SelectedTimePeriod").val());

            var minDate = new Date($("#SelectedTimePeriod").val());
            minDate.setDate(filterDate.getDate() - 7 * $("#SelectedTimeRange").val());
            var maxDate = new Date($("#SelectedTimePeriod").val());
            maxDate.setDate(filterDate.getDate() + 7 * $("#SelectedTimeRange").val());


            $("tbody tr td:nth-child(5)").each(function () {
                var rowDate = new Date($(this).text());
                if (rowDate.getTime() < minDate.getTime() || rowDate.getTime() > maxDate.getTime())
                    $(this).parent().hide();
                else
                    $(this).parent().show();
            });
        }
```

The line that seems to crash IE8 is:

```
$(this).parent().hide();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, also if there is any more information I could provide that could be helpful please let me know.

Comment: have you tried to print out what IE8 thinks `$(this).parent()` is? Might be that IE is grabbing more then it should be or the xpath is to deep. Just a thought

Comment: Well, if I comment out the Hide and break on just the $(this).parent call, the watch window seems to agree that it's the tr element.

Comment: I've found this [article](http://www.code-styling.de/english/jquery-132-causes-problems-at-ie-8) about an issue when hiding `<tr/>` with jquery 1.3.2 (i assume you use a newer version of course). It's worth investigating. Have you tried applying a class to the `<tr>` instead of using `.hide()` ?

Comment: I've tried setting the display value of the css on the tr to none, and it still crashes when I do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be an answer but I have made this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/3kqq3/) and it works in all browsers (IE7->9, FF, Chrome).

I have made some optimizations to your code btw:

```
// cache your "static" elements from the page, no need to query for them all the time
var $table = $('table'),
    $timePeriod = $("#SelectedTimePeriod");

function filterData() {

    // only input[type=checkbox] can be "checked" so just write "input:checked"
    // use .prop() for special attributes like checked, selected, disabled...
    $table.find('input:checked').prop("checked", false);

    // select the value once for TimePeriod
    var timePeriodVal = $timePeriod.val();
    var filterDate = new Date(timePeriodVal);

    var minDate = new Date(timePeriodVal);
    minDate.setDate(filterDate.getDate() - 7);

    var maxDate = new Date(timePeriodVal);
    maxDate.setDate(filterDate.getDate() + 7);

    // your initial selector was too long
    // find the "tbody" once and only select "td". you can omit "tr", "td" only exist in "tr" anyway
    $table.find('tbody')
          .find('td:nth-child(5)').each(function() {

        // select $(this) once and re-use
        var $this = $(this),
            rowDate = new Date($this.text());

        // explicitly mark { } and ';' to avoid misinterpretation by browsers
        if (rowDate.getTime() < minDate.getTime() || rowDate.getTime() > maxDate.getTime()) {
            $this.parent().hide();
        }
        else {
            $this.parent().show();
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: Well, while I'm still mystified as to why my code would crash IE...this works great! Thanks so much for taking the time to write this up, and +1 for pointing out the optimizations to me.

Comment: Er, I was too hasty. I still had the compatibility meta tag in my page, without it the page still crashes.

Comment: I would have though it might have been because of the curly braces, event though it is valid javascript, it is not save to no mention them. At least you have more optimized code ^^ If i get illuminated, i'll post again :-)

Answer (score 2):

A co worker of mine fixed this problem using setTimeout

```
var mili = j$("li.autocompletehover", pnl).length > 0 ? 200 : 0;
setTimeout(function () {
   pnl.hide();
}, mili);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain this is the answer, but it's something to try - IE tends to want to use dynamic table widths.  It may be that the code for this in IE8 is clashing with show/hide.  add "table-layout:fixed" to the table style (css or directly) and manually set the widths of the tds in the first row of the table (which should have the column names, and thus should not be hiding).  Alternately, if you have manually set the width of the table already, then manually set the widths of all but the last td in that first row.  If for whatever reason you are unable or unwilling to apply the width to the first row of tds, then define them with a colgroup prior to the first tr of the table.  (a web search on "colgroup" should show you how to do that relatively quickly).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to have worked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your code is having trouble, but I have many times done projects that do a hide() and show() on a table row without any problems at all in IE8. The first thing I would suggest would be that before you actually do anything to the element, confirm that you are indeed working on the expected row (tr) element and only make the call to .show() or .hide() if you are certain your (this) reference is pointing to the element you are expecting. Second, and potentially a way to make your .each() selection run mach faster would be to only select the rows of the table at that level, then do a sanity check within that first each() block that makes sure you have a valid row, the columns in the row you are working with have valid values. This can potentially make that loop much faster if you have a page of any significant size since jQuery can select the element using native to get to those level of elements.