# Internet explorer crashes on JQuery .hide()

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have the following function to hide and show DIVswith JQuery

```
  function parlement(niveau){
    var optie;
       if(niveau == 'vlaams'){
           if($('[name="federaal"]').is(":visible")){
       $('[name="federaal"]').hide(500);
           } else{
        $('[name="europees"]').hide(500);
           }
       $('[name="vlaams"]').show(500);
        optie = 0;     

       }

          else if(niveau == 'federaal'){
              if($('[name="europees"]').is(":visible")){
      $('[name="europees"]').hide(500);
              }else{
       $('[name="vlaams"]').hide(500);
              }
       $('[name="federaal"]').show(500);
       optie=1;
       }

          else if(niveau == 'europees'){
              if($('[name="federaal"]').is(":visible")){
       $('[name="federaal"]').hide(500);
              }else{
       $('[name="vlaams"]').hide(500);
              }
        $('[name="europees"]').show(500);
       optie=2;
       }

           var arr = $('#parlheading a');
       for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; ++i) {
        if (i == optie) {
            arr[i].style.fontWeight = "bold";
        }
        else{
            arr[i].style.fontWeight = "normal";
        }
}

};
```

Actually, this is a tab box with 3 options, when an option gets clicked, I want to hide the other divs and show the clicked option div. In firefox this works fine, but IE keeps crashing?

Comment: which version of IE? And please provide a demo. What do you mean by "it crashes"? Does the application die or is it just not working?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CE9eg/
Here it doesn't do anything? IE 10, and by crashed I mean really, crash and force shutdown.

Comment: [try this solution using setTimeout](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38162886/1502110) i'd used in another post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not Test with IE10 at the moment, but i refactored your script, which should be running like expected now:

http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/CE9eg/3/

```
$(function () {
    $("#parlheading").on("click", "a[data-parlament]", function () {
        var optie;
        var parament = $(this).data("parlament");

        $('.parlbody[name!="' + parament + '"]').hide(500);
        $('.parlbody[name="' + parament + '"]').show(500);

        $('#parlheading a').css("font-weight", "normal");
        $('#parlheading a[data-parlament="' + parament + '"]').css("font-weight", "bold");
    });
});
```

I've changed your HTML to this:

```
<div id="parlheading">
    <p class="active"><a href="#" data-parlament="vlaams">Vlaams Parlement</a></p>
    <p><a href="#" data-parlament="federaal">Federaal Parlement</a></p>
    <p style="border-right: none;"><a href="#" data-parlament="europees">Europees Parlement</a></p>
</div>
<div name="vlaams" class="parlbody">vlaams</div>
<div name="federaal" class="parlbody">federaal</div>
<div name="europees" class="parlbody">euro</div>
```